# Every devices using IOS13 doesn't display numbers correctly if &nbsp; is used at its end or if the library Intl is used

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ios13, intl

As the title says, IOS13 doesn't display numbers correctly.

Numbers such as 100 000 will be written as 100000, which according to french syntax rules on numbers is not correct. (Kinda like english says that numbers should be written like 100'000 and not 100000).

The problem has been tested with both safari and chrome on physical devices (Iphone 7) and simulated devices (ipad pro, iphone X) and the numbers are never displayed correctly.

There are two ways to reproduce this problem either by using &nbps; at the end of a number (to never separate the number and the sign of dollars) or by using the Intl.formatNumber() method of the popular library.

Here's a (react) snippet of code that can reproduce the bug. It should not be too hard too make it in pure javascript if needs be.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        Incorrect : <span>100 000&nbsp;$</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Incorrect : <span>{new Intl.NumberFormat("fr").format(100000)}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Correct : <span>100 000 $</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also available on codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-wood-29eg7

I am pretty sure that this bug is not related to react or javascript, since it can be reproduced in pure HTML. Source here : https://jsfiddle.net/he72Lvjp/1/

Comment: [SO] is not the place for bug reports: or did you mean to ask a question?

Comment: I was looking for any solutions that I can have. I haven't found any place to reports bugs on apple website, so I though maybe someone was aware of this solutions and could offer me a solution.